# Selectively turning off Devise's flash notices in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

The Devise authentication framework uses flash notices everywhere. This makes it easy to integrate with apps but it leads to  poor user experience sometimes.

I am wondering what's an easy way to selectively turn off some of the Devise flash notices in my Rails 3 app. In particular, I'd like to get rid of the blatantly obvious signed_in and signed_out flashes.

Some searching suggested subclassing the session controller or use [something like this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) but I haven't been able to find any simple solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can customize your devise flash messages with I18n backend which devise supports. If you set *nothing* for particular key, the empty flash message won't be shown, for example for sign_in and sign_out:

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      unauthenticated: 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
      locked: 'Your account is locked.'
      invalid: 'Invalid email or password.'
      invalid_token: 'Invalid authentication token.'
      timeout: 'Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.'
      inactive: 'Your account was not activated yet.'
    sessions:
      signed_in: ""
      signed_out: ""
```

**UPD.**

You should not remove the key otherwise you will get an error.
To not display empty flash messages you should do simple check in the view (for ex. with haml):

```
- unless notice.blank? && alert.blank?
  #flash
    .wrapper
      - unless notice.blank?
        %p.notice= notice
      - unless alert.blank?
        %p.alert= alert
```

Comment: this results in the error message: translation missing: en.devise.sessions.user.signed_out

Comment: Have you delete this key? Try set empty string with quotes as I updated my answer.

Comment: Voldy, if I set a translation to _nothing_ or empty string then I get an empty flash. If I remove the key I get an error.

Comment: @Sim, just check it with `blank?`. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Got it--I thought this logic is internal to devise (it would make sense IMO)

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that its not very good practice to use more than one logical condition on unless. But nice solution though. it helped me.

Comment: For those that come here in the future, this file is `devise.en.yml`.

Answer (score 8):

A better way to hide empty flash messages:  if your message is in a div with class "notice" or "error" CSS3 lets you have a style like this:

```
.notice:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Which is nice because you can then always display the flash div and it'll only show up when there's something there.  I use this to update flash messages in responses from ajax calls which otherwise wouldn't update flash messages because there's no page re-load involved.  It gives a consistent look to messages that come as a result of ajax calls.