# Rails Disable devise flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How I can disable all Devise gem flash messages ("successfully signed in","you logged out")? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicates this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281365/selectively-turning-off-devises-flash-notices-in-rails-3

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to

1. Define each message as a blank string
2. Check the length of the string before you show a flash message.

In your `devise.en.yml` file, specify each message as empty:

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      not_found: ''
      already_confirmed: ''
      not_locked: ''
```

etc. Next, in your layout, check for blank flash strings before you output them.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, :class => "flash #{key}" unless value.blank? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Very elegant! For my devise (2.1.0) just setting the the string to '' did the trick without checking for blank?

Comment: what about session message etc, not working like this

Comment: Would this continue to work if the locale was not `en`?

Answer (score 39):

An answer better suited for me was to override the Devise Session Controller like this

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
    flash.delete(:notice)
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    super
    flash.delete(:notice)
  end

end
```

This safely overrides the create and destroy method removing the flash message

Comment: in Rails 4 and Devise 3.4.1, i had to add this to the routes: devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions"}

Answer (score 8):

This work for me:

```
# app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_action :remove_notice, only: [:destroy, :create]

  private

  def remove_notice
    flash.discard(:notice) #http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-discard
  end
end

# add this line in 'config/routes.rb'
devise_for :users, :controllers => { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

I use `Users::SessionsController` but you can use `SessionsController`, I have just one devise model in this example.

I use `flash.discard(:notice)` but you can use `flash.discard` to remove others types in same time. (method discard exist since rails 3.0)

I prefer this approach, because it's not the role of the view to check if your flash message if blank. If you have a flash message, print it! If you don't want, so don't create flash message ;-)

Comment: does not work with rails 2, but we are in 2018 now :). For Rails3, use `after_filter` instead of `after_action`

Answer (score 7):

I've been able to disable them in a given controller by overriding `is_flashing_format?`:

```
def is_flashing_format?
  false
end
```

I'm using Devise 3.5.6

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 5.0.6 this code will work.

`app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    flash.clear
    super
  end
end
```

Do not forget the routes.

`config/routes.rb`

`devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }`

Answer (score 0):

As of today, just leaving an empty string disable the toast entirelly.
This works :

```
  sessions:
  signed_in: ""
  signed_out: ""
  already_signed_out: ""
```

Answer (score -4):

Devise includes a handy generator to copy all the views into your project:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This way you can edit the views yourself and decide what you want to keep or throw away (flash messages).

Comment: It looks like an answer for another question. You can't disable flash messages with that. See Brandon's answer.

Comment: You can if you display your flash messages in each view, by deleting it. But it seems this question assumes that they're in the layout.