# Disable Responders gem flash message for devise sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We're running both devise and the responders gem in our project.  We have removed the signed_in and signed_up flash messages as described here: [Rails Disable devise flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762798/rails-disable-devise-flash-messages)

Relevant part of config/locales/devise.en.yml:

```
devise:
  sessions:
    signed_in: ''
    signed_out: ''
```

But now upon sign in the flash we receive is "User was successfully created."  We've traced this down to the responders gem. Here's our config/locales/responders.en.yml file:

```
en:
  flash:
    actions:
      create:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.'
      update:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully updated.'
      destroy:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully destroyed.'
        alert: '%{resource_name} could not be destroyed.'
```

I get why it would be saying User was created (the devise session was created, with a resource of user) but everything I've tried so far doesn't remove that message (short of removing the entire responders gem).

I've tried adding a few specific entries with an empty message to the responders.en.yml file:

```
en:
  flash:
    actions:
      create:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.'
      update:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully updated.'
      destroy:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully destroyed.'
        alert: '%{resource_name} could not be destroyed.'
    users:
      create:
        notice: ''
        success: ''
    sessions:
      create:
        notice: ''
        success: ''
```

but we're still getting the same "User was successfully created." flash message upon sign in.

Rails: 4.0.4
Devise: 3.2.2
Responders: 1.0.0

How can I disable this flash message when a user signs in and a session is created?

Comment: isn't the whole case of Responders to actually flash messages?

Comment: @phoet In most cases yes, but in this particular case it shows "User was successfully created" whenever someone signs in, as it's "creating" the session :)

Comment: Same issue here, good to hear someone else has it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across this myself and thought I should come back with a bit of an answer on this. You were really close on your attempt, but had the nesting slightly wrong.

```
en:
  flash:
    actions:
      create:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.'
        alert: '%{resource_name} could not be created.'

      ...your other responders here...

    devise:
      sessions:
        create:
          notice: ''
```

The only real difference from your question is that `sessions` is nested under `devise`.

Good luck!

Comment: Very interesting. I have sense abandoned the responders gem, largely due to this issue. Can someone else confirm this works and then I'll accept the answer? If I have a chance I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: As a sidenote, the `notice` and `alert` keys should be the `responders` keys you have stipulated. For example, we use `success` / `failure` which will make `devise > sessions > create > success` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Jay's answer. If you are overriding Devise's SessionsController, you must remove the devise key in the locale file. So it will be:

```
en:
  flash:
    actions:
      create:
        notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.'
        alert: '%{resource_name} could not be created.'
        ...your other responders here...

    sessions:
      create:
        notice: ''
```