# Disable devise flash messages not working by emptying strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have emptied the flash messages' strings in devise.en.yml and the message is no longer appearing on my page, but I still get that 'Dismiss' word. Any ideas on how to disable that word from appearing there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Disable devise flash messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762798/rails-disable-devise-flash-messages)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. I have emptyed the strings and that didn't solve my issue

Comment: @Vlad From the duplicate: "Next, in your layout, check for blank flash strings before you output them." Have you done this as well?

Comment: same issue after empty string, its showing full message